# Was Leonard Nimoy a vegetarian?

Tags: star-trek, actors, food, spock

In the episode "All Our Yesterdays" of *TOS*, Spock reveals he is a vegetarian. The other day I was reading that Leonard was a vegetarian in real life. But I also read a 1967 [magazine](http://www.leonardnimoy.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1464) where he said his favorite food was steak.

So was he really a vegetarian or did someone make a mistake?

Comment: No; http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_of7mShM5N1g/TCAO9VNnzxI/AAAAAAAABuc/Bf5bykmEav0/s1600/bbq_01.jpg

Comment: He might have become one later, but I've found no documentation that Nimoy was a vegetarian outside of vegan sites who state it. The closest you get is that it's a "fact" in his IMDB profile, but again, without any citation and users contribute most of the content there.

Comment: How does Spock being a vegetarian relate to Nimoy being one?

Comment: @Skooba - it may have influenced his decision

Comment: @Valorum: I'm skeptical; this is the man whose biography is titled *I Am Not Spock*.

Comment: @Kevin - Shall I just wait here while you look up the title of the *second autobiography* he wrote?

Comment: @Valorum: Obviously we must dig Mr. Nimoy up and interrogate him to resolve this paradox.

Comment: Thing about being a vegetarian is, you usually *become* one.

Comment: Neither of his autobiographies 'I am not spock' and 'I am spock' [searchable on googlebooks] contains the term(s) vegetarian or vegan. However I have found books online that refer to him as a 'well known celebrity vegetarian' the issues are: are they correct and if so when did he become one.

Comment: https://www.vintagecookbook.com/singers-swingers-in-kitchen-leonard-nimoy/ on the other hand his contribution to this 1967 cookbook was meatless.

Comment: There are a large number of references on line to his vegetarianism/vegan status, such as: http://sfglobe.com/2015/02/27/26-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about-leonard-nimoy-from-star-trek/ Of course these may just be repeating copying a misidentification between Spock and Leonard.

Comment: @SimonBucher-Jones: Yeah, it feels like one of those "Harry Potter facts" which has been passed around so often that people now think it's the truth.

Comment: I think if it were true there'd be a mention in his biographies, or an interview with a vegetarian magazine. I think Spock has been conflated with Nimoy, and his view reported as the same. Its been enhanced by the fact he both likes vegetarian food, and has submitted recipes to cookbooks with dual meat and 'vulcan vegetarian options'. But liking a variety of foods and offering others a variety, isn't being a 'vegetarian' in terms.

Comment: Don't forget that it's possible to have been a vegetarian at one time and not be a vegetarian at another.

Comment: @Skooba because actors often draw from aspects of themselves to build out the characters they portray. In this case, the thinking might be that the idea to make Spock a vegetarian originated from a suggestion by Nimoy, drawing from his own life (I have no idea if this is the case), just as he came up with the Vulcan salute by drawing from Jewish religious ritual he remembered witnessing as a child (something Nimoy has recounted on-camera more than once).

Comment: But what about Nimoy's third book, _I am Also Scotty_?  https://frinkiac.com/meme/S13E08/50634.jpg

Answer (score 14):

## Probably not.

As you mention yourself in your question, he was quoted once as saying his favourite food is steak.  Despite the many vegetarian / vegan lifestyle web sites that claim he is a vegetarian, I see no hard evidence of this.

Rather, there seems to be evidence to the contrary.  Here he is **enjoying BBQ** with his cast mates during the filming of *The Original Series*:

[image]

Also, here is an animated version of Nimoy (which he provided the voice for) in *The Simpsons* **enjoying a hot dog**:

[image]

I suspect that, if he felt strongly about vegetarianism, he would have objected to this portrayal of himself as a meat eater.

Comment: in that same episode he's also portrayed as being able to teleport

Comment: @Valorum : I suspect he would have no moral objection to being portrayed as a teleporter.  While somewhat itinerant, teleporters are by and large good people.

Comment: Not if it's a vegetarian hot dog.

Comment: It's worth noting that his favourite food being steak and him being a vegetarian are not mutually exclusive concepts. _If_ he was a vegetarian, it's just as plausible it was for reasons other than him disliking the taste of meat.

Comment: Has anyone seen his son's documentary about him? Surely if he was a vegetarian that must mention it?

Answer (score 8):

In the [*Star Trek Cookbook*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Cookbook) (published 1999), Leonard Nimoy provided a "favourite recipe" for fans, *"Kasha Varnishkas a la Vulcan*".

It contains beef bouillon broth. He notes that it tastes especially delicious when combined with the cooked meat juices from a pot roast.

> *This is my favorite dish. The recipe was handed down by my mother, who brought it from her village in the Ukraine, which is a small town in Western Vulcan.*
>
> 1 cup kasha (whole-wheat or buckwheat groats)
>   1 egg or egg white only as a substitute
>   **2 cups beef or vegetable bouillon broth or boiled water**
>   1 16-ounce package bow-tie pasta
>   1/2 medium onion, finely chopped
>   1 tablespoon vegetable oil
>   1 pinch of salt or garlic salt
>
> *Heat water or bouillon mixture to rolling boil, then keep on low heat at a slow boil. Saute onion in oil until just transparent and set aside. Separate egg white from yolk. Stir kasha and egg white into a medium-sized bowl then pour mixture into a heavy saucepan, stirring constantly until the particles separate. Add the bouillon broth or boiling water and salt to taste. Stir the mixture, cover tightly, and reduce heat to simmer for 10 minutes. Cook the bow ties in boiling water until soft, drain and set aside. After the liquid has all been absorbed, mix the kasha with the cooked pasta and sauteed onions and serve. **This dish is particularly delicious when served with pot roast gravy.** If you want to stay traditionally Vulcan vegetarian, you can make a brown mushroom gravy and use that instead. Serves four.*

Comment: It's like vegan's..I ain't never heard of no vegetarian who doesn't tell you they are at every opportunity